# Rails server responds 404 when sending show/update/destroy request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with my Ruby on Rails web app.

I have a model class called **Source**, 
and in my *routes.rb*, I add the following configuration:

```
namespace :admins do
  resources :sources do
    collection do
      get 'batch_new'
      post 'batch_create'
    end
  end
end
```

When I run `rake routes`, I can see:

```
admins_source GET    /admins/sources/:id(.:format)  admins/sources#show
              PUT    /admins/sources/:id(.:format)  admins/sources#update
              DELETE /admins/sources/:id(.:format)  admins/sources#destroy
```

But when I send these requests via clicking the link or form submitting, 
I always get 404.

Here is the code in **views/admins/sources/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for [:admins, @source] do |f| %>
  <% if @source.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@source.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this source from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @source.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :url %>
    <%= f.text_field :url %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my code of the **Destroy** link on the **views/admins/sources/index.html.erb**:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', admins_source_url(source), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

And here is the code in the **SourcesController**

```
def destroy
    @source = Source.find(params[:id])
    @source.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to admins_sources_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
end
```

This problem only occurs in production environment. 
Development environment is just fine.

I also did asset precompiling for production env before starting my server(unicorn).
I've no idea how to fix this issue.

Here's my environment:

OS: Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS

Ruby version: 2.0.0-p0

Rails version: 3.2.13

Rails server: unicorn 4.6.2

Database for production: MySQL

Database for development: sqlite3

Comment: Can you post the form code?

Comment: OK, I added some codes that may lead to this problem.

Comment: I've also thought about the foreign-key constraint, which MySQL has but sqlite doesn't have. However, I checked my tables in MySQL and found no foreign keys in any table. Maybe `rake db:migrate` does not create any actual foreign keys.

Comment: how does your schema look like?

Comment: `sources id, timestamps, name:string, url:string` 
`feeds id, timestamps, source:references, ...`

Actually in table 'feeds', the column 'source_id' is just an integer column, not FK.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you have some other error (like a migration that was a problem, or a uncompiled asset). Just look in the production logs to find the real error, as what you posted here just should work (If you had 1K points I would not ask this, sorry if you did check those logs :) )

Comment: Hi, Hugo. There is nothing wrong in my production log except missing of favicon.ico. I added some log to the **SourcesController#destroy** method, changed log level to debug, and restarted my server, but still no error about my issue was reported. It seems **SourcesController#destroy** was never called.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.
It is the browser that can't send requests other than GET when hyperlinks are clicked, even though the attribute `data-method="delete"` exists.

I have deleted both **SourcesController#show** and the corresponding view because sources are so simple that even **index.html.erb** can show all the details of all the sources.

Because of this deletion, the GET request on /admins/sources/:id which should be DELETE loses its target view.

I changed

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', admins_source_url(source), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

to

```
<%= button_to 'Destroy', admins_source_url(source), method: :delete %>
```

then all is fine except for the confirmation message, but that doesn't bother me too much.

However, there is still a question:
How are the requests dispatched under development env, since hyperlinks with `:method => :delete` work perfectly?

Comment: Yes you are right. I was driven in the wrong direction because you wrote "But when I send these requests via clicking the link or form submitting", so I thought the problem had to be in the target controller...